# DbStatus value -1 vs 0 in different environments

Tags: asp-classic, vb6, odbc

Here is my code for retrieving data via ODBC in VB:

```
Dim Ssql
Dim dbstatus 
Dim rs

'*************  

 Ssql =  " Select * from User_Access A Where A.User_pwd ='1234' "
  set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
  rs = DB.execute(Ssql,dbstatus)      
  Response.Write(dbstatus)
  If dbstatus <> 0 Then
        'Error code here
  Else
        'code here 
  END IF

'*************
```

The code is working ok . On successful execution of sql statement the dbstatus value is giving -1 . But according to the code it should return 0 for further execution . For other than 0 it will give Error .

I'm executing this on sql server 2005 and in windows 7.

***But the same code On successful execution of sql statement the dbstatus value is giving 0 on some other enviornment where ODBC version and sql server version is different .

Can anyone help me out . 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you using the Connection.Execute Methode in ADO and VB the second Parameter represents the affected rows.

[image]